# How to get last 16 binary digits of a negative number and concatenate them?

Tags: c, int, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I'm working on with some bitwise operators and I want to extract the last 16 binary digits of a number and do an operation with them. I basically want to see a negative int like 0xFFFFFFFF and then extract the LSB `FFFF` and concatenate them with `0` so that I end up with a zero so that it looks like `0x0000FFFF`instead. I only care about smaller negative numbers so the LSB should be all the info I need.

Here is my approach in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int a = -1, c = 0;
    short b = (short)a;
    printf("a is %x\nb is %x",a,b);
    c = (0 << 16) | b;
    printf("\nc is %x\n", c); 
    return 0;
}
```

My thought process being that I can convert my `int a` to a short so that it looks like `FFFF` instead of `FFFFFFFF` I will have a better time. Unfortunately for me, this just prints out `ffffffff` for the variables

Comment: the cast in `(short)a` is unnecessary because any wider value will automatically be truncated down

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc thanks. Is there any reason to use short when it comes to bit manipulation?

Comment: it's needed in some cases but not in this case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have doesn't work because the bitwise-OR operator (`|`) sets any bit which is set in either operand.

You want to use the bitwise-AND operator (`&`) to mask out the bits you don't want.  This clears any bit which is clear in either operand.

Change this:

```
c = (0 << 16) | b;
```

To this:

```
c = b & 0xFFFF;
```

And your output will be:

```
a is ffffffff
b is ffffffff
c is ffff
```

Comment: so for the 16 MSB I would say `c = b & 0xFFFF0000`?

Comment: @user3470987 Almost.  That will give you `0xFFFF0000`.  If you want `0x0000FFFF` you have to do `c = (unsigned int)(b & 0xFFFF0000) >> 16`.  The cast is needed to prevent the possibility of `1` bits being shifted in from the left.